# Dev Platform - Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, permissions, profile

I just created a developer org for a customer presentation. I have created a special object from the object manager.

When creating, a warning message appears:

> *"Permissions for this object are disabled for all default profiles. You can activate object authorizations in authorization sets or by editing custom profiles".*

Once created, as my object does not appear in the "launcher" I went to the profiles and I put all the rights on this object for all users but it still does not appear and I can not affiliate it to an application...
Do you have an idea for a resolution?

Comment: Also make sure the tab is visible for the profiles

Comment: Do you have a Tab created for your object?

Comment: Thanks i have created my tab and it's work

Answer (score 2):

A Custom Object will appear in the App Launcher only if you have [Created a Tab for your custom object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_custom_object_tabs.htm&type=5).

It is most likely that you haven't created a Tab yet for your Object, once created it should be visible in the launcher.

Also, to be able to associate it to any other Object, you will need to ensure that you establish the relationship between the Objects.